# GitLab API - GET Merge request JSON format

Tags: find-and-replace, gitlab

I'm getting my merge requests with this command:

```
curl --request GET--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/4/merge_requests/85"
```

And I get my merge request from GitLab like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "iid": 1,
  "project_id": 3,
  "title": "test1",
  "description": "fixed login page css paddings",
  "state": "merged",
  "created_at": "2017-04-29T08:46:00Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-04-29T08:46:00Z",
  "target_branch": "master",
  "source_branch": "test1",
  "upvotes": 0,
  "downvotes": 0,
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Administrator",
    "username": "admin",
    "state": "active",
    "avatar_url": null,
    "web_url" : "https://gitlab.example.com/admin"
  }
```

My problem is, that my code needs a JSON without **null's** instead I need **None**. I know I can replace it but how can I do that, if I cant save this merge request in a variable because of the errors I get.

Comment: I don't see any "nulls" in your output. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: "avatar_url": null for example. I mean I will get nulls for sure

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: I use a Linux VM (Ubuntu)

Comment: pipe it through `sed` https://ss64.com/bash/sed.html

Comment: What do you mean with pipe it through?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: Thanks I have to have a look cause I didn't really get it. PS: I work with pycharm where I also implement the GET function of the merge request. Does it still work for me?